# How to pass two values when a bookmark is clicked in crosstab?

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi, cognos-tm1

I'm working with a crosstab in cognos now.

Page 1 contains crosstab

Page 2 contains list

Fact - Revenue Dimension - Product line, Year

If I click on the revenue (cell value) it should goto the particular record in another list which is located in a separate page. Actually I'm passing data item values. I have to pass two data item values which corresponds to the cell value (Horizontal and veritical). However, the fact could not be bookmarked. I don't know why. Do you have suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Does the link not appear against the number? I know it's tricky to get drill-throughs working in crosstabs. I've never needed to use a bookmark though.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Master-Detail relationship?
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.8.4.0.doc/ug_cr_rptstd_id12005cr_rptstd_modrep_create_master_deta.html

Comment: You are right. Master-Detail relationship is just sharing results between two items. It's like a relationship. We can pass the values using Master-detail relationship but My question is on passing the values **when a bookmark is clicked**.

Comment: Sorry for late answer: you can unlock the Cross-Tab and add hyperlinks or drill-through actions inside the xtab fact cells.